# pander not working in gmailR

Tags: r, gmail-api, pander

I have set up gmailR to share the data frames through emails. I am getting below error. Please help

```
email <- send_message(mime(from="xxxx@yyyy.com", to="xxxx@yyyy.com",
                          subject="Text Email Testing", body = pander_return(pander(head(iris, 3)))))

Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Warning message:
In charToRaw(x) : argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27706177/564164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
paste(pander_return(pander(head(iris, 3))), collapse="\n")
```

`length(pander_return(pander(head(iris, 3))))` is `24`, but the function seems to expect a character vector of length `1`. `paste` concatenates it, using a line break `\n` as a seperator.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It's working BUT the columns width is a problem now. My table is distorted.

Comment: View your email in an email client that supports a [nonproportional font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) or send it as <pre>-formatted HTML.